# ¿Hay alguna forma de separar los resultados del true y false en filter?

Tags: python-3.x

¿Hay alguna forma de separar los resultados del true y false en filter?
Tengo este código como un ejemplo:

```
users = ["pedro(premium)","jorge","juan(premium)","pablo"]
premium_users = list(filter(lambda a: a.endswith("(premium)"),users))
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "separar"? Crear dos listas, una con los usuarios premium  y otra con los que no?

Comment: @abulafia eso mismo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` no puede "separar" valores, solo darte los que cumplan la condición. En el módulo `itertools` tienes `filterfalse()` que te devuelve sólo aquellas para las que la condición es falsa.

Así que una forma obvia de hacerlo es en dos sentencias, una para los que son premium y otra para los que no:

```
import itertools
condicion = lambda a: a.endswith("(premium)")
premium_users = list(filter(condicion, users))
non_premium = list(itertools.filterfalse(condicion, users))
```

La forma más estándar y más legible de hacerlo sería sin embargo mediante un bucle `for` explícito (que además es más eficiente pues recorre la lista una sola vez):

```
premium_users = []
non_premium = []
for u in users:
  if u.endswith("(premium)"):
    premium_users.append(u)
  else:
    non_premium.append(u)
```

Pero si lo que te va es la programación funcional, las comprensiones de listas, y el código en una línea que una semana después ya no recuerdas cómo funcionaba, puede que te guste esta (ineficiente) solución:

```
non_premium, premium_users = (list(grupo) for k, grupo in 
      itertools.groupby(sorted(users, key=condicion), key=condicion))
```

### Ampliación

Como comenté antes creo que la mejor solución es la del bucle explícito. Sin embargo puede ser útil tenerlo en una función genérica, que haga la separación de una lista dada bajo una condición arbitraria que recibiría como parámetro. Es fácil escribir la función:

```
def discriminar(lista, condicion):
  cumplen = []
  no_cumplen = []
  for elem in lista:
    if condicion(elem):
      cumplen.append(elem)
    else:
      no_cumplen.append(elem)
  return cumplen, no_cumplen
```

y en tu caso la invocarías así:

```
premium_users, non_premium = discriminar(users, lambda a: a.endswith("(premium)"))
print(premium_users)  # => ['pedro(premium)', 'juan(premium)']
print(non_premium)    # => ['jorge', 'pablo']
```

Comment: no sabia que las funciones lambdas se podrían usar dentro variables, de lo que uno se viene a enterar :0

Answer (score 3):

Mucho más simple, con un comprensión de listas:

```
users = ["pedro(premium)","jorge","juan(premium)","pablo"]
premium_users = [x for x in users if x.endswith("(premium)")]
non_premium_users = [x for x in users if not x.endswith("(premium)")]
print(premium_users) => ['pedro(premium)', 'juan(premium)']
print(non_premium_users) => ['jorge', 'pablo']
```

La comprensión es la manera compacta de escribir

```
premium_users = []
for x in users:
    if x.endswith("(premium)"):
        premium_users.append(x)
```

Comment: Esta solución (como la primera propuesta de Abulafia) Implica recorrer dos veces el mismo iterable. Lo cual con iterables grandes puede hacer que un programa se demore mucho mas.